# Insatall phpMyAdmin in CentOS vps

Tags: centos, putty, phpmyadmin

I can make a account in host1free.com.And now I had a vps server In this vps server opreting system is centOS and I can not use it before so I am newbie for this and I want to install a phpmyadmin in my vps server.
I am using Putty for that and I write   `yum install phpMyAdmin` it give a message that package is not avilable.What I did do.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is not in the standard repositories for CentOS

Try this to get it
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-fedora-redhat-linux-installing-phpmyadmin-webtool/

FYI this is the top result when I google'd your question

Comment: I already used this but it is not working.Can you tell me anyother method to install it.Thanks.........

Comment: What part of this method is not working? Any method of installing will involve getting the code and installing it in more or less the same way.